# Numpy conditional check with stop

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need your help. I want to walk over a three dimensional array and check in one direction the distance between two elements, if it is smaller the value should be True. As soon as the distance gets higher than a certain value the rest of the values in this dimension should be set to False.

Here is an example in 1D:

```py
    a = np.array([1,2,2,1,2,5,2,7,1,2])
    b = magic_check_fct(a, threshold=3, axis=0)
    print(b)

   # The expected output is :
   > b = [True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

For a simple check, the result with `a <= threshold` would be and is not the expected output:

```py
   > b = [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]
```

Is there an efficient way to this with numpy? This whole thing is performance critical.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't follow, is `a` your input array or the distance already? If `a` is your input, shouldn't the result be `[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False]`? Because `7-2>3`, and that condition is not reached before.

Comment: @Divakar that one is the result of simple boolean masking `b < threshold`

Comment: @kmario23 Yeah just figured that out. Edited question to clarify that.

Comment: @Divakar looks good now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) along that axis  -

```
np.minimum.accumulate(a<=threshold,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [515]: a
Out[515]: array([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1, 2])

In [516]: threshold = 3

In [518]: print np.minimum.accumulate(a<=threshold,axis=0)
[ True  True  True  True  True False False False False False]
```

Another with thresholding and then slicing for `1D` arrays -

```
out = a<=threshold
if ~out.all():
    out[out.argmin():] = 0
```

Comment: This is very elegant! Seems like the function is made just for cases like these. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more approach using [`1st discrete difference`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
In [126]: threshold = 3
In [127]: mask = np.diff(a, prepend=a[0]) < threshold

In [128]: mask[mask.argmin():] = False

In [129]: mask
Out[129]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```